# How can i use vuetify 3.3.4 date picker component in my project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, datepicker, vuetify.js

I am trying to use latest vuetify 3 (3.3.4 version - lab) date-picker component.
I created a date-input component in my project component folder.

/components/DateInput.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-menu
      v-model="menu"
      :close-on-content-click="false"
      :nudge-right="40"
      transition="scale-transition"
      offset-y
      min-width="290px"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-text-field
          v-bind="props"
          :value="dateFormatted"
          variant="outlined"
          append-inner-icon="mdi-calendar"
          @change="onChange"
          @input="updateDate"
        ></v-text-field>
      </template>
      <v-date-picker
        :value="getDate"   
        @change="onChange"
        @input="updateDate"
      ></v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    /**
     * Date on ISO format to be edited.
     * @model
     */
    value: {
      type: String,
      default() {
        return ""
      },
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      menu: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    dateFormatted() {
      return this.input ? new Date(this.input) : "";
    },
    getDate() {
      /**
       * Return ISO 8601
       */
      let date = this.input ? new Date(this.input) : new Date();

      let month = 1 + date.getMonth();
      if (month < 10) {
        month = `0${month}`;
      }
      let day = date.getDate();
      if (day < 10) {
        day = `0${day}`;
      }
      return `${date.getFullYear()}-${month}-${day}`;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(val) {
      console.error(val)
    },
    updateDate(val) {
      this.menu = false;
      console.error(val)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

/App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="6">
        <date-input></date-input>
      </v-col>  
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  
</template>

<script>
import DateInput from './components/DateInput.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    DateInput,
  },
}
</script>
```

When i try to select a date i always get an error like below.

[image: Select Error]

Where am i doing wrong ?
I deployed the project to codesanbox, here is the codesanbox link.

https://codesandbox.io/p/github/eguvenc/test/main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [bug in the VDatePicker component](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/17601). It's already fixed, but unless you want to switch to the [nightly build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vuetify/nightly), I think you have to wait for the next release.

However, the problem can be avoided by passing in a correct [`:modelValue`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#props-model-value) property (you seem to use a non-existent `:value` property). Note that `:modelValue` has to be an array containing Date objects. So try something like:

```html
      <v-date-picker
        :modelValue="getDate"
        @update:modelValue="updateDate"
      ></v-date-picker>
```

(note that there is no `@change` event anymore, and `@input` is `@update:modelValue` in Vue 3).

and have `getDate` return a Date array:

```
getDate() {
  const date = this.input ? new Date(this.input) : new Date()
  return [date]
}
```

Comment: i tried it but it does not work for me.

Comment: Right, yes, sorry, VDatePicker expects a Date object, not a string, check the updated answer

Comment: Hi, thanks, but when i format the date i get date errors. Which date format do i need to use in my project date comes as string how can i convert to the format it should be.

Comment: Are you asking about the [date time string format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_time_string_format)?

Comment: When i format the date  as string i get errors did you try it ? For instance format date as 23-10-2023 you will see the errors.

Comment: You didn't look at the link, did you? The format has to be `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `DD-MM-YYYY``

Comment: yes i tried -- > https://codesandbox.io/p/github/eguvenc/test/main  <-- check the code sandbox open a new tab see the console errors.

Comment: Your `getDate` returns a string array, but is has to be a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) array. Remove the part where you extract the string from the Date and just return the date, like the version of `getDate` in my answer

Comment: Ok, sorry for the misunderstanding. It finally works. In the meantime, we just have to pay attention to this. I am writing these lines only for those who need clean information like me. getDate returns the object as you said, but the dateFormatted() function we use to enter the modalValue should return the string type.